# VStack shows error "Instance method 'sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)' requires that 'Int' conform to 'Identifiable'"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The line VStack shows error "Instance method 'sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)' requires that 'Int' conform to 'Identifiable'" but i think i dont make any mistake there? did i?

It feel like error come from my sheet complaining my Int should conform to 'Identifiable' however is not Int is an 'Identifiable' since it's primitive? how would i solve this problem?

```
    struct SheetView: View {

    @State var bindingItemDiscounts: [Double] =
    [ 0.99, 0.25, 0.31, 11.99, 19.99, 0.1, 0.5]
    @State var discountMoreThanTen: Int?
    var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) { <- this line
        Button {
            discountMoreThanTen = bindingItemDiscounts.count
        } label: { Text("Check Discounts") }

    }.sheet(item: $discountMoreThanTen) { newValue in
        if discountMoreThanTen ?? 0 <= 10 {
            
            List(bindingItemDiscounts, id: \.self) { discount in
                Text("Discount : \(discount)")
            }
            
        }
    }
 }
 }.
```

Answer (score 5):

1. There is no such concept as *Primitive* in **Swift**. The *"Primitives"* you refer to are normal `struct`s.
2. `Int` does not conform to `Identifiable`.

To fix your problem just extend `Int` to conform to `Identifiable` like so:

```
extension Int: Identifiable {
    public var id: Int { return self }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Binding<Item?>` **sheet**. The **Item** is a type, so it must conform to **Identifiable** in order to be identified uniquely.

Also, `Int` is not a primitive in Swift. `Int` is basically a **Type** just like your other custom data types, so you need to make it **Identifiable** manually.

Add this extension in your file will fix this problem:

```
extension Int: Identifiable {
  public var id: Self { self }
}
```

If UUID() is required, then use this instead:

```
extension Int: Identifiable {
  public var id: String {
    return UUID().uuidString
  }
}
```